# sed replace newline character with space

Tags: sed, terminal, osx, fish

**How can I use sed to replace new line character with any other character?**

#### Input:

```
 I cannot conceive that anybody will    
 require multiplications at the rate of 
 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ...      

 -- F. H. Wales (1936)
```

#### Desired output:

```
I cannot conceive that anybody will require multiplications at the rate of 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ...  -- F. H. Wales (1936)
```

I've tried:

```
> pbpaste | sed 's/\n/ /g'
```

but it outputs the same thing as input. I know it's a newline char because I've checked it with `cat -ev` and it prints `$` as expected.

**What else would be a good command to do this?**

---

This shows where there is extra space between new line. I want to remove that as well. So it's like a sentence with spaces.

```
> pbpaste | cat -ev
 I cannot conceive that anybody will    $
 require multiplications at the rate of $
 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ...      $
                                        $
 -- F. H. Wales (1936)                  ⏎
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tr` is probably a better tool for this job. Try the following

```
pbpaste | tr '\n' ' '
```

With your input, I get the following output.

```
I cannot conceive that anybody will require multiplications at the rate of 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ...  -- F. H. Wales (1936)
```

Comment: Do you know why `sed` doesn't work? Would like to find out so I don't make a mistake? `sed 's/I/---/g'` works just fine for replacing `i`. I also tried it with `sed -E` to get extended RE and it doesn't work. What flavour of RE does it use? None of common character sets seems to work; I tried `\s{1}` for white space and that just replaced `s`. 

Comment: `sed` works on individual lines. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed for alternate solutions

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `sed` (even without the GNU `-z` slurp extension) by using the `N` command in a loop:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/ *\n */ /;ta' -e 'P;D' input
 I cannot conceive that anybody will require multiplications at the rate of 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ... -- F. H. Wales (1936)
```

For discussion of an essentially equivalent command see for example **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "="** in [Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I](https://catonmat.net/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @QIS.

There are a couple of reasons why sed won't work for you.

One is that, by default, `sed` processes its input a line at a time, and for that reason, `sed` will never see a newline as **part** of a line.  It's a delimiter **between** lines, by default.

Another is that, although GNU `sed` implements the `'\n'` representation of a newline, BSD `sed` (the version found on OSX) does not.

Just for any future GNU `sed` users who may read your question, GNU `sed` can be told to treat the input file as a NUL-delimited list of strings using the `-z` option.  Assuming that your input contains no NUL bytes, this could be an option for GNU `sed` users:

```
$ pbpaste | sed -z 's/\n/ /g'
```

One trivial (and non-recommended) method would be to take advantage of the fact that when `echo` receives unquoted newlines as a result of command substitution, it replaces them with spaces.  Also, `echo` will convert multiple spaces (or newlines) to a single space.  Thus, it is likely that this will work for you also:

```
echo $(pbpaste)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `fmt` and `par` are good tools for re-formatting text.

Both of them can be used to reformat your text into a single long line after the linefeeds have been replaced with spaces (e.g. with `tr`):

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt | fmt -w 999
I cannot conceive that anybody will require multiplications at the rate of 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ...    -- F. H. Wales (1936)

$ tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt | par w999
I cannot conceive that anybody will require multiplications at the rate of 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ... -- F. H. Wales (1936)
```

Note that the output of fmt and par is slightly different.   fmt has four spaces between the `...` and the `--`, while par reduces them to one space.

---

**More on `fmt` and `par`:**

`fmt` is a standard utility that has been around for decades, and should be available on almost any unix system. On GNU/Linux systems, it's in the GNU `coreutils` package.

```
$ fmt < input.txt 
I cannot conceive that anybody will require multiplications at the rate
of 40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ...

  -- F. H. Wales (1936)
```

It is, however, very simple and does not allow much control over how the paragraphs can be reformatted, nor does it perform any special handling of leading and/or trailing characters (like `>` quoting in email or `/* ... */` comments), which can lead to a jumbled mess.

[`par`](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) is much more flexible and capable.  It can reformat C style `/* ... */` comments and boxed text, email messages with multiple levels of quoting, and more.  The following example doesn't show what it's really capable of.

```
$ par < input.txt 
I cannot conceive that anybody will require multiplications at the rate of
40,000 or even 4,000 per hour ...

  -- F. H. Wales (1936)
```

The following example (from `man par`) begins to show `par`'s capabilities:

```
Before:

   John writes:
   : Mary writes:
   : + Anastasia writes:
   : + > Hi all!
   : + Hi Ana!
   : Hi Ana & Mary!
   Please unsubscribe me from alt.hello.

After "par Q+:+ q":

   John writes:

   : Mary writes:
   :
   : + Anastasia writes:
   : +
   : + > Hi all!
   : +
   : + Hi Ana!
   :
   : Hi Ana & Mary!

   Please unsubscribe me from alt.hello.
```

I've been using it daily from within vi/vim since I discovered the 1990s to reformat emails that I'm writing (or emails from others with unreadable long lines), code comments and other text.  IMO, par is an indispensible, must-have program.